# Extremely high mouse sensitivity that prevents right click in touch screens

Tags: unity, ubuntu-touch, mouse, touchscreen

Although everything looks fine with my touch screen and Ubuntu, there's a problem that I don't understand how solve.

Now in Ubuntu (Unity) there's an option to enable right-click by holding the mouse left button's clicked. Now this is perfect, except that when I put my hand on the screen to do it, my hand moves a little bit, which disables calling right-click. Apparently it's expected that I'm a robot that never moves, shakes, with super perpendicular pressure on the screen with nano-meter precision.

Realistically speaking, it looks like that the tolerance on the mouse position to accept right-clicks is zero... Is there a way to make this a little bit more tolerant?